# Dragonfly Goggles

Tags: science-based, biology, vision

Ahh insects, such fascinating creatures with fascinating traits, but sadly as I have found out most are only available to them and not us thanks to the square cubed law.

Maybe the following traits, with the combination of optics and biology can be possible. So my idea is:

- an advanced human eye three times larger with the ability to see UV radiation as well as the full color spectrum normal to humans.
- the mind and eye of this human will be further adapted to have the *capacity* of handling near 360 vision.

  - although the adapted human will be required to wear special goggles in order to actually see in 360.

So my question is can the eye and mind be enhanced like this without hurting the human? While at the same time using special goggles made to mimic 360 vision and maybe even on some level, compound eyes?

Comment: Compound eyes are good at detecting movement avoid predator or searching for prey, otherwise the acuity of human eyes is 100x better than the dragon fly's comparing the number of light sensitive cells squeezed into a small area. Certain species of bird triple us in this aspect.

Comment: I think this could be 2 questions. Can an eye be adapted to an insects? and can goggles give an insectlike view? I edited to add a few missing words eg 'see' uv light, but wasn't sure how to fix the last sentence of the now second paragraph.

Comment: *"can an eye be enhanced"* and *"can goggles be made"* should rather be asked as separate questions, unless you can edit this one to show how goggles and eye enhancements are connected.

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by creating an advanced human eye and then asking about goggles. Are you asking if (1) the goggles can give you the intended result of a modified eye or (2) are you saying the eye is modified and then the goggles are added on top of that modification giving a further advancement? (3) the eye is modified but only works properly with the goggles? see? right now, I can't figure out what you are asking? (will be the first to admit that it could just be me. Your sentence is confusing)

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I'm asking to modify the eye to see UV and have the potientail to handle all the info brought  by 360 vision and have the goggles added on top to give actual 360 vision.

Comment: ok. that makes it a bit clearer. I edited the question again to try put that across. feel free to rollback any changes. it still looks like two questions to me. you may have more luck with the 360 and goggle part of the question if you ask a new question for that bit.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps okay thanks for the advice, but wouldn't it get duplicated

Comment: The answer to every "can I do this?" question is "yes, given enough Clarkean Magic."  Clarke's third law: any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.  Do you have a specific question in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ultraviolet vision

The human eye *can* see in UV—if the lens is removed:

> You may have heard that digital cameras can be made sensitive to infrared light by removing the IR filter found inside, but did you now that something similar can be done with the human eye? People who have aphakia, or the absence of the lens on the eye, have reported the ability to see ultraviolet wavelengths. Claude Monet was one such person.
> <sub>[The Human Eye Can See in Ultraviolet When the Lens is Removed](https://petapixel.com/2012/04/17/the-human-eye-can-see-in-ultraviolet-when-the-lens-is-removed/)</sub>

However, without the lens, the eyes are more vulnerable to UV damage.

### Eye size

I see no reason why eye size can't be increased to three times the current size, although you'll need to also modify the skull so that it all fits. (Obviously this is not a change you can make to living humans.)

Some primates have very large eyes compared to the size of their body. It's actually a little unsettling:

[image]
<sub>[Tarsiers - The Big-Eyed, Ancient, Nocturnal Mammal](http://www.factzoo.com/mammals/tarsiers.html)</sub>

### 360 degree vision

There's a big difference between dragonflies and humans here due to the placement of the eyes:

> Eyes that face forward on a skull suggest a predator. Forward facing eyes allow for binocular or stereoscopic vision, which allows an animal to see and judge depth. Predators need this depth perception to track and pursue prey. Cats and owls are excellent examples of predators that use forward facing eyes when hunting their prey. Monkeys also have forward facing eyes that give them depth perception needed to swing and leap in their tree top habitat. Humans have forward facing eyes as well.
>
> Animals with eyes that are located on the side of its head would suggest a prey animal. Side eye placement allows for greater peripheral or side vision. This enables the animal to see predators approaching from the side as well as from behind. This vision is very important for protecting an animal when it is grazing or feeding.
> <sub>[How to "Read" a Skull: Eye Placement and Size](http://skeletonmuseum.com/okc-education/15/how-to-read-a-skull-eye-placement-and-size.htm)</sub>

Even with larger eyes, vision will not be 360 degrees. The skull would need to be significantly redesigned so that the eyes are on the sides of the head, not the front, but even this will probably have blind spots in front of and behind the head.

### Goggles

You don't actually need to make any modifications to the eye to get the effects you want. The solution is quite mundane actually: all you need is VR goggles and a camera that sees in 360 video and UV. Each eye gets a fisheye image that shows UV light. Of course, training will be needed so this isn't super nauseating and confusing, but I think it's possible for the human brain to adapt (since our brains are [very adaptable](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/nov/12/improbable-research-seeing-upside-down)).

Comment: keep in mind humans only keep track of a small portion of our visual field as it is, adding more to the field will only decrease visual acuity. plasticity can only go so far.